# How to import MathML into Word from an external formula editor?

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, compatibility, mathml

I prefer drawing my mathematical formulas with [MyScript](https://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math/index.html#), because its recognition works better than MS Word 2016. So this online tool produces a MathML code, which I copy into the clipboard and simply paste into MS Word. At my first attempts, Word was able to automatically [convert a MathML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430775/copy-mathml-into-word-to-use-as-equation?) into a formula. But why is Word not able to do the same with the third attempt? Is there anything wrong with the settings?

Comment: Does it raise any error message? What is the formula you're pasting into Word?

Comment: There is no error message by MS Word 2016. Word just keeps the pasted code as plain text, instead of converting it. Here is an example for such a MathML code: <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'> <msub> <mrow> <mi> H </mi> </mrow> <mrow> <mn> 2 </mn> </mrow> </msub> <mi> O </mi> <mo> &#x21CC; <!-- rightwards harpoon over leftwards harpoon --> </mo> </math>

Comment: You should edit the information into the question. /// Does the formula you used in your first attempt still get pasted correctly?